# Is it possible for a macro to paste into an existing macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a process for my employees in excel. I have written several macros to update several things based on user input.

Is it possible to copy the newly created information in cell A28:H28 and get it to paste into a specific line in a preexisting macro?

I have created the following which copies the information and then opens the relevant macro but don't know if it is possible to then paste the info in the existing macro (called "Month").

```
Sheets("New Month Or Client").Select
Range("A28:H28").Select
Selection.Cut
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.Goto Reference:="Month"
```

The code for the month macro is:

```
Sub Month()

    ' NewMonth Macro
    ' AF Report

    Sheets("AF Report").Select

        ' Copy & Paste main data

        Range("AB8:IV41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC8").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        ' Copy & Paste Top Ten data
        Range("AA49:IW59").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AG49").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("B32:B41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AA50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("F32:F41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AB50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("D32:D41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("H32:I41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AD50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    ' MD Report

    Sheets("MD Report").Select

        ' Copy & Paste main data
        Range("AB8:IV41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC8").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        ' Copy & Paste Top Ten data

        Range("AA49:IW59").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AG49").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("B32:B41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AA50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("F32:F41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AB50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("D32:D41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("H32:I41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AD50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    ' KK Report

    Sheets("KK Report").Select

        ' Copy & Paste main data

        Range("AB8:IV41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC8").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        ' Copy & Paste Top Ten data

        Range("AA49:IW59").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AG49").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("B32:B41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AA50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("F32:F41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AB50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("D32:D41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("H32:I41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AD50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    ' AO Report

    Sheets("AO Report").Select

        ' Copy & Paste main data

        Range("AB8:IV41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC8").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        ' Copy & Paste Top Ten data

        Range("AA49:IW59").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AG49").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("B32:B41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AA50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("F32:F41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AB50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("D32:D41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("H32:I41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AD50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    ' TM Report

    Sheets("TM Report").Select

        ' Copy & Paste main data

        Range("AB8:IV41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC8").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        ' Copy & Paste Top Ten data

        Range("AA49:IW59").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AG49").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("B32:B41").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AA50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("F32:F41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AB50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("D32:D41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AC50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

        Range("H32:I41").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Range("AD50").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    ' Copy Last Month Pasted Data

    Sheets("Pasted Report").Select

        Columns("A:AR").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy

        Columns("AZ:AZ").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Columns("A:AR").Select
        Selection.ClearContents

        ' Clear Aff No's & Device

        Columns("CT:CV").Select
        Selection.ClearContents

        Columns("CX:DB").Select
        Selection.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific to get a clear view on what you need

Comment: Your question is vague - do you want the code of your macro to change based on inputs from another worksheet? Or do you just want the output of one macro to change based on inputs from another worksheet? It would help if you showed both macros in their entirety, particularly the point of data transfer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by pasting it into a macro.  Application.Goto can be used go to a sheet reference or code  - but you won't be able to paste a range of values into some VBA code (a macro).  Does 'Month' identify a specific cell on a worksheet, or a whole worksheet, or a VBA procedure? This will Cut and Paste the data:  `Worksheets("New Month Or Client").Range("A28:H28").Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Month").Range("A1")`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839232.aspx

Comment: As others have said, it is a bit unclear, but if I read it at face value, you could create an `Range` argument in the Sub that you want to pass the data into it and pass that range into like `MySub Range("A28:H28")` where `MySub` is defined `Sub MySub (Optional rng as Range)`. Making it optional means you can pass the range or not. In this way, you can work with that range in the sub.

Comment: Sorry it's vague!! I want to paste the contents of Cells A28:H28 into an existing macro called "Month" - sounds like from what I have read above that it's not possible though??? Thanks

Comment: Can we see the 'Month' macro code?  It's probably possible - we just need to understand what you're asking.

Comment: @HazelPopham - Yes. It's most likely possible. I assume you want "Paste" the contents of the range because you wish to work with them in the macro? If not, let us know what *exactly* you want to do with it (and show us the `Month` macro code, perhaps). If you do want to work with the contents, you can use the suggestion I already provided.

Comment: The "month" macro is quite long so I've shortened it below. 

   Sub Month()
   
   ' NewMonth Macro
   

    ' AF Report

    Sheets("AF Report").Select
    
   ' Copy & Paste main data

    Range("AB8:IV41").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AC8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

   .. more code

    End Sub

Contents of cell A1 I want to paste - 

   ' WM Report

    Sheets("WM Report").Select
    
   ' Copy & Paste main data

    Range("AB8:IV41").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AC8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

   ... more code

    End Sub

Comment: I can't format the code so that it shows properly - is there any other way I can show you???

Comment: I've saved the code to One Drive - https://onedrive.live.com/redir?page=view&resid=6B478A9537E4D0F3!2612&authkey=!AKa-PW9vqlXvbp4

Comment: So what I wish to paste into the top of this (above 'AF Report ) is another piece of code (identical to the ' AF Report code) but it will have a different name in the comment and it will select a different sheet called ?? Report - depending on what the user called it when they created it.

Comment: I have just tried to do this manually and recording it with a macro and there was nothing, so I'm afraid it's not possible to modify a macro using another macro.

Comment: @Dominique It is certainly possible to modify macros using another macro, when using the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3" reference, and then using `VBComponent`s & `CodeModule`s.  It is a bit involved, but you can research it if it strikes your curiousity.

Comment: It is possible - just not by recording a macro, but I seriously don't think that's what Hazel is after.

Comment: I've edited your code into the question. In the future, please do not use third-party sites to host your code. The body of your post should hold all relevant information necessary to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I can see your code (have added it to your question, but waiting on peer review).

Your passing a range of cells to a procedure and copy/pasting values - no need to select the sheets or ranges each time; just reference them.

Have a look at OFFSET and RESIZE to as I expect you can pass a single range and calculate the other ranges from there.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    'ThisWorkbook is the file containing the VBA code.
    'Can also use ActiveWorkbook, Workbooks("Name.xlsx"), etc.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case wrkSht.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "AnotherSheet"
                'Do nothing.
            Case Else
                With wrkSht
                    Month .Range("AB8:IV41"), .Range("AC8"), _
                          .Range("AA49:IW59"), .Range("AG49")
                End With
        End Select
    Next wrkSht

End Sub

Sub Month(Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Range3 As Range, Range4 As Range)

    Range1.Copy
    Range2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

    Range3.Copy
    Range4.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! You people on here are so clever! This doesn't actually solve my initial problem but it does replace all that code! That's the difference between people who know how to code properly and people like me who have learnt from recording macros and piecing bits together!!

My problem is that each month there will be a new sheet called ? Report and the people who will be using running the code above won't be able to update the code with the new sheet name and I obviously don't know what it will be called in advance. So my idea was to write a macro to update this code? Or another way?

Comment: Will it run on all sheets in the workbook except a named few?  You could use a `For Each Worksheet in Thisworkbook.worksheets`, or maybe have a list in a specific sheet and then look at each row in turn - there's plenty of ways to gather information off the user. (I started learning by recording macros to - back in about '97 I think).

Comment: It needs to run on all sheets in the workbook except for three. How would I exclude it from running on them? (theres hope for me yet then....maybe!!!)

Comment: I've updated the code to work on all worksheets in the workbook except for the named worksheets - this should do the trick.

Comment: Literally the most awesome thing that's happened to me this year!!! You are amazing!! :)

Comment: Feel free to add it as the accepted answer - also will probably be best not to call it MONTH as that's a VBA keyword to.